# PHP Script with cURL works on one server...does not work on other server

Tags: php, curl, ssl

Thanks in advance for all your help. Here is my issue:

I have a dual node server configuration with two servers that (should) be exactly identical. Both have PHP installed. I am able to run my cURL PHP script flawlessly on one node, but not on the other. Here are the verbose (debug) outputs from both instances:

Known working (node 2):

```
stderr=* About to connect() to company.sharepoint.com port 443
*   Trying 191.234.148.26... * connected
* Connected to company.sharepoint.com (191.234.148.26) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: /C=US/ST=WA/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft/CN=*.sharepoint.com
*        start date: 2014-04-14 22:01:07 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-04-13 22:01:07 GMT
*        subjectAltName: company.sharepoint.com matched
*        issuer: /DC=com/DC=microsoft/DC=corp/DC=redmond/CN=MSIT Machine Auth CA 2
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: company.sharepoint.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1021
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Error (node 1):

```
* About to connect() to company.sharepoint.com port 443
*   Trying 191.234.148.26... * connected
* Connected to company.sharepoint.com (191.234.148.26) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to company.sharepoint.com:443 
* Closing connection #0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Curl error: Unknown SSL     protocol error in connection to company.sharepoint.com:443 ' in     /opt/CLA2/sharepoint/sharepoint.php:391
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/CLA2/sharepoint/sharepoint.php(39): getAuthCookies('t=EwDwAk6hBwAUG...', 'https://paychex...', '1')
#1 {main}
   thrown in /opt/CLA2/sharepoint/sharepoint.php on line 391
```

Any suggestions? I'm baffled why two supposedly identical nodes would have different results.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `Unknown SSL protocol error` means the SSL negotiation failed. This is possibly due to incompatible ciphers or SSL version. You could try explicitly setting the cipher and version to work around this.

Using the [Qualys SSLtest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html), the supported ciphers are:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

and the supported versions are `SSLv3` and `TLSv1`.

So you can do

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER, 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA');
```